# OnCheckChanged Event of asp:CheckBox Not Firing When Unchecked From Within Nested GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I have conducted a lot of searches which included checkchanged or OncheckChanged keyword:

[ASP.NET CheckBox does not fire CheckedChanged event when unchecking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457136/asp-net-checkbox-does-not-fire-checkedchanged-event-when-unchecking)

https://forums.asp.net/t/1311576.aspx?Checkbox+not+firing+when+unchecking+using+OnCheckedChanged

[OnCheckedChanged event not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6596767/oncheckedchanged-event-not-firing)

[OnCheckedChanged event handler of asp:checkbox does not fire when checkbox is unchecked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404528/oncheckedchanged-event-handler-of-aspcheckbox-does-not-fire-when-checkbox-is-un?rq=1)

But this just doesn't seem to be working although I applied all suggestion from the links given above

I am tring to fire a **CheckChanged Event** From nested gridview, whose `DataSource` gets binded in parent grid's `OnRowDataBound` event.

My **aspx markup**

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvDocSchedule" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="table table-striped color-black"
    OnRowDataBound="gvDocSchedule_RowDataBound" DataKeyNames="UserID">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <img alt="" style="cursor:pointer" src="UserPanel/images/Plus12.png" />                
                <asp:Panel ID="PanelSchedule" runat="server" Style="display:none">
                    <asp:GridView ID="gvScheduleDayNTime" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField ="ScheduleDay" HeaderText="CheckInTime1"/>
                            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField ="CheckInTime1" HeaderText="CheckInTime1"/>
                            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField ="CheckOutTime1" HeaderText="CheckOutTime1"/>
                            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField ="CheckInTime2" HeaderText="CheckInTime2"/>
                            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField ="CheckOutTime2" HeaderText="CheckOutTime2"/>
                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnForChkBox" runat="server" value="No" /> 

                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CBoxAvailabilityTime1" ViewStateMode="Enabled" Checked="false" Enabled="true" EnableViewState="true" runat="server" Text="See Free TimeSlots For Booking In Time1" AutoPostBack="true"  OnCheckedChanged="CBoxAvailabilityTime1_CheckedChanged" />
                                    <br />
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CBoxAvailabilityTime2" runat="server" Text="See Free TimeSlots For Booking In Time1" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="CBoxAvailabilityTime2_CheckedChanged" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                </asp:Panel>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField ControlStyle-Font-Bold="true" DataField="UserFirstName" HeaderText="Doctor's First Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="UserLastName" HeaderText="Doctor's Last Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="SpecializationName" HeaderText="Doctor's Specialization" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="HospitalName" HeaderText="Hospital" />

    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I was trying it with `CBoxAvailabilityTime1`CheckBox. As you guys can see ViewStateMode and EnableViewState has been taken care of not only in server tag but also in content page's tag, also these properties are true for master page

Parent Grid gets binded when user press a button and nested grid gets binded in parent's `OnRowDataBound` event

Here is My **aspx.cs code**

```
protected void CBoxAvailabilityTime1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow gvParentRow in gvDocSchedule.Rows)
        {
            if (gvParentRow.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                GridView gvDocSchedulesGetChildGrid = (GridView)gvParentRow.FindControl("gvScheduleDayNTime");
                if (gvDocSchedulesGetChildGrid != null)
                {
                    foreach (GridViewRow gvChildRow in gvDocSchedulesGetChildGrid.Rows)
                    {
                        CheckBox CBoxAvailabilityTime1 = (CheckBox)gvChildRow.FindControl("CBoxAvailabilityTime1");
                        CheckBox CBoxAvailabilityTime2 = (CheckBox)gvChildRow.FindControl("CBoxAvailabilityTime2");

                        if (((CheckBox)CBoxAvailabilityTime1).Checked)
                        {
                            CBoxAvailabilityTime2.Enabled = false;
                        }
                        if (!((CheckBox)CBoxAvailabilityTime1).Checked)
                        {
                            CBoxAvailabilityTime2.Enabled = true;
                        }
                   }
              }
          }
     }
}
```

With this setup CheckChanged Event Fires on Checking.
On Checking it hits `Page_ Load` **skips** `if(!IsPostBack)` (as `AutoPostBack=true`) and then control is directly transferred to
`CBoxAvailabilityTime1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)` **event handler function**
but on the other hand it doesn't fire on unchecking it `postsbacks` goes to `Page load` again **Skips** `if(!IsPostBack)` and does nothing instead of calling
`CBoxAvailabilityTime1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)`

**"Note:-"** `Page_Load` is not involved. I can't bind parent grid in page_load,
`!IsPostBack` because I dont need to bind it at first time when page gets loaded rather its binding happens inside a button click event, if a button is clicked only then parent grid must get binded.

**Update 1:-** **This is how I bind data to parent grid**

I am calling this function in a button click event

```
protected void BindDataToGridViewDocInArea()
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmdFillGridDocInArea = new SqlCommand("some query with parameter here", con)
            cmdFillGridDocInArea.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AID", ddlAskArea.SelectedValue);
            SqlDataAdapter sdaFillGridDocInArea = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdFillGridDocInArea);
            DataTable dtFillGridDocInArea = new DataTable();
            sdaFillGridDocInArea.Fill(dtFillGridDocInArea);
            if (dtFillGridDocInArea.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                gvDocSchedule.DataSource = dtFillGridDocInArea;
                gvDocSchedule.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {
                lblError.Text = string.Empty;
                lblError.Text = "No Record Exists Against Requst Specified";
            }
            con.Dispose();
         }
    }
```

Comment: How do you bind data to gvDocSchedule? Could you show the code?

Comment: should I edit my question or fiddle it?

Comment: Please post minimum viable code. Or, show you something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24444238/296861) so that we can reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Tested a stripped down version of you snippet. It seems to be working. When you check `CBoxAvailabilityTime1`, it disables `CBoxAvailabilityTime2`. When you uncheck `CBoxAvailabilityTime1` the other one is enabled again.

However this is only when the DataBinding of `gvDocSchedule` is inside an `IsPostBack` check. When it's not the checkboxes will always go to their default unchecked state after PostBack.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        //this works
        gvDocSchedule.DataSource = LoadFromDB();
        gvDocSchedule.DataBind();
    }

    //this does not
    gvDocSchedule.DataSource = LoadFromDB();
    gvDocSchedule.DataBind();
}
```

Or in your case something like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        BindDataToGridViewDocInArea();
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't bind my gridview in page load I have mentioned it already, in my question, my gridview binding has to take place after a button click. What should i do in this case should I call button click event in page_load like btn_click(sender, e); this will also misbehave because there are few selections to be made from dropdownlists and I am providing ids from dropdowns to sql query which is in button click event

Comment: Even if I move `BindDataToGridViewDocInArea();` to a Button click event it still works as it should.

Comment: I tried to move `BindDataToGridViewDocInArea();` to `Page_Load` inside `(!IsPostBack)` still CheckChanged event firing on checking and not hitting on unchecking. When you moved `BindDataToGridViewDocInArea();` in button click u take it off from `!IsPostback` right?

Comment: Also I don't understand with `AutoPostBack` on set for check boxes it is posting back everytime it is hitted, why would it hit some thing inside `!IsPostBack`. And my check box is unselected by default when it appears, it gets selected right, and disables the other but when I again try to click it to unselect it goes to page load **Skips** `IsPostBack` and does nothing instead of calling checkedchanged event and checkbox remains checked as i did it in first place

Comment: Yes I did. The only thing I did use was my own function to bind data to the Grid. Now I'm taking a good look at `BindDataToGridViewDocInArea`. It seems you use a value from `ddlAskArea`. What happens if you give `@AID` a fixed value for testing?

Comment: Ok let me check

Comment: And it seems you don't understand the asp.net page life cycle. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/asp.net/4948/page-life-cycle#t=201701252024259503626) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251157/what-is-a-postback)

Comment: I did it and for once somehow or other it seems that it hitted CheckChanged event on unchecking and instead of enabling Cbox2 again the child grid displayed empty. I clean and rebuilt but it never hitted checkchanged event again on unchecking with @AID static